# Printing separate datatypes on top of two template stacks (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, types, stack

c++ novice here. I'm currently trying to write a program involving templated stacks that can handle two separate data types, int and Student objects. While the stack logic of the program works fine, I'm not sure how to go about printing the value at the top of the stack for each data type. Right now I have two possible ideas, overload the '<<' operator for a class (which one, I'm not sure) or write overloaded functions for TopStack() (i.e. `template <> int Stack<int>::TopStack() const`). I have the latter implemented, but not correctly. Does anyone know what the most efficient way to accomplish this is? I'm open to any suggestions.

I'll post the relevant parts of my code so you can see what I'm talking about.

```
template <class DataType>
struct StackNode
{
    DataType data;                      // data can be of any type
    StackNode<DataType> *next;          // point to the next node
};

template <class DataType>
class Stack
{

private:
    StackNode<DataType> *top;                                 // point to the top node of the stack
    int maxSize;                                              // maximum stack size
    int numNodes;                                             // number of nodes in the stack


public:
    Stack();                                                  // constructor, create a stack with size 10
    ~Stack();                                                 // destructor

    bool isEmpty() const { return (top == 0); }               // check if the stack is empty
    bool isFull() const { return (numNodes == maxSize); }     // check if the stack is full
    void Push(const DataType &elem);                          // push a node onto the top of the stack
    void Pop();                                               // pop a node from the top of the stack
    int TopStack() const;                                // return data from the top of the stack
};

struct Students
    {
        char lastName[20];               // student's last name
        char firstName[20];              // student's first name
        int IDNumber;                    // student ID #
        Students();                      // constructor
        void PrintStudent();             // print a student's information
    };

void Students::PrintStudent()
{
    cout << "\nID# " << this->IDNumber << " - " << this->lastName << ", "
         << this->firstName << endl;
}

// in main() snippet
// if the user asks for top of stack
case 3:
    if (!intStack)            // I use a boolean to switch the stack being accessed
        sstack.TopStack();    // Student stack
    else if (intStack)
        istack.TopStack();    // Int stack
    break;
```

Comment: You should overload << for your class, int already streams itself fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int TopStack() const;                                // return data from the top of the stack
```

should be

```
DataType TopStack() const;                                // return data from the top of the stack
```

because the type of the data varies with the type of the stack.

Implemented something like this:

```
template<typename DataType>
DataType Stack<DataType>::TopStack() const
{
   Assert(top != nullptr);
   if (top == nullptr)
     return DataType();
   return top->data;
}
```

However, what does your class do that `std::stack<T>` does not do?  Or even `std::vector<T>` (which is, amusingly enough, usually a better stack than `stack`).

The code that is using your `Stack<DataType>` will know the type of the data, either because of the type of the variable it is talking to, or a template parameter it itself has.  Add a `operator<<` overload for your Student class, so you can print them without jumping through any special hoops.

If you find overloading `operator<<` to be scary, you could write a free-standing `Print` function with `int` and `Student const&` overloads.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This program is actually an assignment for my Data Structures class. My professor has a vendetta against STL and prefers we create our own stack classes to better learn how they function at a basic level. I need to read up more on overloading the << operator.

Comment: Ok, I've added the following to my Students class:

    `ostream& operator<< (ostream& output, const Students s)
{
 output << "\nID# " << s.IDNumber << " - " << s.lastName << ", "
   << s.firstName << endl;
 return output;
}`

Comment: Well, that won't work?  It needs to be a free function, not part of Students.  I'd also advise taking a `const Students& s` not a `const Students`, because why make an extra copy when you don't need to?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what you wrote. I've moved the operator<< method out of the struct declaration and recompiled, but I'm still getting a memory address as a return from top->data. Is it supposed to automatically see sstack.TopStack() as a student datatype? 

`cout << "\nTop of stack is: " << sstack.TopStack() << endl;`